# Error: self signed certificate in NodeJS HTTPS Request

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, axios, certificate

I'm fairly new to NodeJS and I'm trying to implement HTTPS request from NodeJS (backend) directly to a middleware api hosted in IISNode with a GoDaddy certificate. I have another repo for my view (frontend) and all the calls to the middleware api through the browser are working with the GoDaddy certificate. The calls work fine with HTTP using Axios. When making the call to the middleware api with HTTPS from the NodeJS backend I'm getting:

```
Error: self signed certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1058:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:636:8)
```

It's really weird that the frontend repo communicates with no issue to the middleware via the browser but the NodeJS backend calls will not. I have tried using Axios in the backend with no luck and cert errors. I switched to HTTPS and the GET calls are working, but POST calls give me the error above.

I have read tons of posts and examples regarding self-signed certs but I'm using a cert that is generated from GoDaddy. Here are some code snippets I've tried:

Axios:

```
    const SSLAgent = new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        passphrase: process.env.PASSPHRASE,
        pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../") + process.env.PFX),
        ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../") + process.env.CRT_BUNDLE)
    });


    const fetchData = () => axios.get(`${process.env.MIDDLE_WARE_URL}/something`, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        httpsAgent: SSLAgent
    });


    const uploadData = () => {
        const form = new FormData();
        form.append("data", fs.createReadStream(dataPath));
        return axios.post(`${process.env.MIDDLE_WARE_URL}/data`, form, {
            headers: {
                ...form.getHeaders(),
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            httpsAgent: SSLAgent
        });
    };

    const fetchItemImage = (ItemID: number) => axios.get(`${process.env.MIDDLE_WARE_URL}/item/${ItemID}/image.png`, {
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`},
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../") + process.env.PFX), passphrase: process.env.PASSPHRASE}), ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../") + process.env.CRT_BUNDLE)
    });
```

HTTPS:

```
        const SSLAgent = {
        rejectUnauthorized: true,   
        passphrase: process.env.PASSPHRASE,
        pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../") + process.env.PFX),
        ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../") + process.env.CRT_BUNDLE)
    };

    const middleServer = express;
    const middle = express.Router();
    https.createServer(SSLAgent, middleServer).listen(443);

    let data;
    const dataOptions = {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    };
    const fetchData = () => middle.get("/data", (req, res) => {
        console.log("The req is: ", req);
        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log("The Fetch Data Res: ", res);
            data = res;
        }
        data = [];
    });

    const uploadStuff = () => {
        const form = new FormData();
        form.append("Stuff", fs.createReadStream(stuffPath));
        const stuffOptions = {
            headers: {
                ...form.getHeaders(),
               "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            form
        };
        return  middle.post("/stuff", (req, res) => {
            req.params(stuffOptions);
            res.on("data", () => {
                console.log("The post response is: ", res);
            });
            res.on("error", (error) => {
                console.log("The post error is: ", error);
            });
        });
    };
```

Also, here is my IIS web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="iisnode" path="iis.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
                <add name="iisnode-socketio" path="iis.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
            </handlers>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="my_middleware">
                        <match url="/*" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                        </conditions>
                          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTPS_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                    </rule>
                        <!-- Don't interfere with requests for logs -->
                    <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                      <match url="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.js\.logs\/\d+\.txt$" />
                    </rule>
                        <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                      <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                    </rule>
                        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the     /public folder -->
                    <rule name="StaticContent">
                      <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
                    </rule>
                        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js application entry point -->
                    <rule name="DynamicContent">
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
                        </conditions>           
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="iis.js" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                    </rule>
                    <rule name="SocketIO" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
                        <match url="socket.io.+" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="iis.js" />
                    </rule> 
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
            <webSocket enabled="false" />
            <iisnode debugHeaderEnabled="true" promoteServerVars="AUTH_USER,AUTH_TYPE,LOGON_USER" />
            <security>
                <authorization>
                    <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                    <add accessType="Allow" users="?" verbs="OPTIONS" />
                    <add accessType="Allow" users="*" roles="" />
                </authorization>
                <requestFiltering>
                    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
                </requestFiltering>
            </security>
            <defaultDocument>
                <files>
                    <add value="iis.js" />
                </files>
            </defaultDocument>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to get the Axios GET request to work. When using an httpsAgent, you have to put the root certificate and the issued certificate in the same array. ```httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        "ca": [fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../") + process.env.CRT_BUNDLE), fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../") + process.env.PFX)],
        "passphrase": process.env.PASSPHRASE
    })``` Still struggling with the POST requests, I now get a 400: BAD REQUEST on the POST.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by: 1. Raising the request limits for maxAllowedContentLength, multipart/form-data, image, and binary headers, 2. the initial and maxRequestBufferSize. 3. Adding to my bodyParser.urlencoded {limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit: 5000} and {limit: "50Mb"} to my bodyParser.json. 4. I stopped using form-data and sent up a handmade object based on the file interface from Multer. Things are saving perfectly to the database now.